# What are my options when I want to find a good interpolation for a coordinate in an irregular grid of values?

Tags: python, spatial-interpolation

I have a list points and their values that cover an area like so:

```
#x, y, value
list  = [
(1.123, 1.232, 15),
(1.121, 2.323, 12),
(1.124, 3.451, 17),
(1.120, 4.593, 06),
(1.121, 5.638, 09),
(2.123, 1.232, 19),
(2.121, 2.323, 72),
(2.124, 3.451, 13),
(2.120, 4.593, 99),
(2.121, 5.638, 04), and so on...]
```

I want to write a function `interpolateValueAtCoordinate(x, y)` that gives me a good interpolation of a value at the specific coordinates.

What could I do?

Comment: Does this SciPy section give ideas: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. As others mention, check Scipy for existing interpolation solutions.

Answer (score 2):

if you've got SciPy available look at [interp2D](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)

Comment: unfortunatelly it segfaults :(

Comment: does the example on the aforementioned webpage work for your installation?